# How to call the tornado.queues message externally

Tags: python, tornado

I used tornado to do a simple websocket client to get the push, but I do not know how to handle tornado.queues in another file.
Using    print (que.get ()) to get the data similar to `<tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x106a940b8>`

a.py

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop, PeriodicCallback
from tornado import gen
from tornado.websocket import websocket_connect
from tornado.queues import Queue
que = Queue()
class Client(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ioloop = IOLoop.instance()
        self.connect()
        self.ioloop.start()
    @gen.coroutine
    def connect(self):
        ws = yield websocket_connect('ws://127.0.0.1:8001/')
        while True:
            msg = yield ws.read_message()
            que.put(msg)
            print(que.get())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Client()
```

b.py

```
import a
awe = a.que
while True:
    print(awe.get())
```

b.py how can I output a.py data?

I just touch python soon, if possible, please post the full code, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tornado.queue.Queue` is not thread-safe and is intended for use within Tornado applications which are generally single-threaded and event-driven. You need to do one of two things:

1. Use Tornado everywhere and make `b.py` use coroutines and events, following the same restrictions on blocking code as elsewhere in Tornado.

   ```
   # b.py
   import a
   @gen.coroutine
   def f():
       while True:
           print((yield a.que.get())
   ```
2. Use the thread-safe `queue.Queue` from the standard library. Writing to an unbounded thread-safe queue from Tornado is easy (use `put_nowait()`). Reading from one (or writing to a bounded queue) is trickier and it's often easiest to dedicate a thread to the task (unless you have a large number of queues):

   ```
   # a.py
   que = queue.Queue()
   executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
   @gen.coroutine
   def connect(self):
       ws = yield websocket_connect(...)
       while True:
           msg = yield ws.read_message()
           que.put_nowait(msg)
           print((yield executor.submit(que.get)))
   ```